# Show only first child in dropdown

Tags: taxonomy, dropdown

I have a dropdown showing a custom taxonomy with multiple levels (children). Below is the code for it. Can someone please explain how I can limit the children shown? For instance, at the moment it shows:

> Parent
>   -> Child
>   -> Child of Child

I only want it to show:

> Parent
>   -> Child

Thanks! :)

```
function my_dropdown_categories( $taxonomy, $current_selected = '', $include = null ) {
// Get all terms of the chosen taxonomy
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('orderby' => 'name'));

// our content variable
$list_of_terms = '<select id="location" data-placeholder="Choose your area..."  class="selectboxSingle" name="location">';

if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) foreach($terms as $term){

    // If include array set, exclude unless in array.
    if ( is_array( $include ) && ! in_array( $term->slug, $include ) ) continue;

    $select = ($current_selected == $term->slug) ? "selected" : ""; // Note: ==

    if ($term->parent == 0 ) {

        // get children of current parent.
        $tchildren = get_term_children($term->term_id, $taxonomy);

        $children = array();
        foreach ($tchildren as $child) {
            $cterm = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy );
            // If include array set, exclude unless in array.
            if ( is_array( $include ) && ! in_array( $cterm->slug, $include ) ) continue;
            $children[$cterm->name] = $cterm;
        }
        ksort($children);

        // OPTGROUP FOR PARENTS
        if (count($children) > 0 ) {
        //     $list_of_terms .= '<optgroup label="'. $term->name .'">';
             if ($term->count > 0)

                 $list_of_terms .= '<option class ="group-result" value="'.$term->slug.'" '.$select.'>' . $term->name .' </option>';
        } else
            $list_of_terms .= '<option value="'.$term->slug.'" '.$select.'>'. $term->name .' </option>';
        //$i++;

        // now the CHILDREN.

        foreach($children as $child) {
          //   $select = ($current_selected == $child->slug) ? "selected" : ""; // Note: child, not cterm
             $list_of_terms .= '<option value="'.$child->slug.'" '.$select.'>'. $child->name.' </option>';
        } //end foreach

        if (count($children) > 0 ) {
            $list_of_terms .= "</optgroup>";
        }
    }
}

$list_of_terms .= '</select>';

return $list_of_terms;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_term_children()` is by purpose recursive, it will always get all children and is not configurable.

[`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) is more generic function for terms retrieval. Using `parent` argument for it will only retrieve one level of children (while `child_of` will retrieve all). See linked documentation in Codex for details.

Comment: Something like this? 

`$tchildren = get_terms($taxonomy,array('parent' => get_queried_object_id(),));`

I'm not sure how to implement it properly, since the dropdown is dynamically populated, and that code is a bit over my head :/